# Classical mapping in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, sqlalchemy, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm new to MongoEngine and it looks like we need to create sub classes of the class `Document` from the `mongoengine` to model our DB. I'm a little concerned here because this violates the Dependency Inversion from the SOLID principles. So if I need to use another database at a later point of time, I will have to change my domain model classes which I shouldn't really be doing.

SQLAlchemy overcomes this by providing a beautiful [classical mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings). Using this, the database dependent code is separated from my domain model, so I don't really need to worry about the database provider and I can easily abstract the details away should I have a need to change my database.

Is there a equivalent of this for MongoDB, preferrably in MongoEngine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pymongo's official [doc](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tools.html#orm-like-layers) provides a list of the existing ORM/ODM and frameworks but to my knowledge they all implement the [Active Record Pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) (just like django ORM), which as you said, violates the SOLID principles but is good enough for many simple use cases.

MongoAlchemy, which was inspired by SQLAlchemy uses a concept of [session](https://github.com/dayorbyte/MongoAlchemy/blob/master/test/test_documents.py#L83) so it may be closer to what you are looking for but the project is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to map an object to document schema using mongoengine.

Let's create a document class for a user:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField


class UserDocument(Document):
    username = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)
    email = StringField(required=True)
```

Now add a class method that creates new users:

```
from mongoengine import disconnect, connect, Document, StringField


class UserDocument(Document):
    username = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringField(required=True)
    email = StringField(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        data = UserDocument(username=cls.username, password=cls.password, email=cls.email)
        connect('test_collection')
        data.save()
        disconnect('test_collection')
```

As I understand your question, your issue in this example is that UserDocument would be aware of mongoengine thus violating the dependency inversion principle. This can be solved with a child class.

First allow inheritance in UserDocument:

```
...
class UserDocument(Document):
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
    username = StringField(required=True)
    ...
```

Next we build the child:

```
from user_document import UserDocument


# Maps object to schema
class User(UserDocument):
    def __init__(self, *args, **values):
        super().__init__(*args, **values)
```

Next add a create method:

```
from user_document import UserDocument


# Maps object to schema
class User(UserDocument):
    def __init__(self, *args, **values):
        super().__init__(*args, **values)

    def create(self, username, password, email):
        self.username, self.password, self.email = username, password, email
        User.new()
```

Now our User object inherits the UserDocument fields. UserDocument.new can be accessed directly or through the child with User.new().

```
from model import User

    username, password, email = 'cool username', 'super secret password', 'mrcool@example.com'
    User.create(User, username, password, email)
```

The User object is aware of UserDocument which in turn depends on mongoengine.

I apologize if I misunderstood or used incorrect vocabulary to describe the example solution. I'm relatively new, self-taught, and have no friends who code which makes discussion difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered in the first 6 chapters of [CosmicPython/Architecture Patterns With Python](https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/preface.html).
However, in those chapters it uses SQLAlchemy with mappers.

The book does have a section with an example for other ORMs that use an ActiveRecord style - like mongoengine - in
[Appendix D: Repository and Unit of Work Patterns with Django](https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/appendix_django.html#appendix_django).

First the models are defined.

Please note the following example may be hard to follow without any background and so I recommend reading the first 6 chapters of CosmicPython if the example below is unclear.

[`src/djangoproject/alloc/models.py`](https://github.com/cosmicpython/code/blob/appendix_django/src/djangoproject/alloc/models.py)

```py
from django.db import models
from allocation.domain import model as domain_model


class Batch(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    eta = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def update_from_domain(batch: domain_model.Batch):
        try:
            b = Batch.objects.get(reference=batch.reference)
        except Batch.DoesNotExist:
            b = Batch(reference=batch.reference)
        b.sku = batch.sku
        b.qty = batch._purchased_quantity
        b.eta = batch.eta
        b.save()
        b.allocation_set.set(
            Allocation.from_domain(l, b)
            for l in batch._allocations
        )

    def to_domain(self) -> domain_model.Batch:
        b = domain_model.Batch(
            ref=self.reference, sku=self.sku, qty=self.qty, eta=self.eta
        )
        b._allocations = set(
            a.line.to_domain()
            for a in self.allocation_set.all()
        )
        return b


class OrderLine(models.Model):
    orderid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    qty = models.IntegerField()

    def to_domain(self):
        return domain_model.OrderLine(
            orderid=self.orderid, sku=self.sku, qty=self.qty
        )

    @staticmethod
    def from_domain(line):
        l, _ = OrderLine.objects.get_or_create(
            orderid=line.orderid, sku=line.sku, qty=line.qty
        )
        return l


class Allocation(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line = models.ForeignKey(OrderLine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @staticmethod
    def from_domain(domain_line, django_batch):
        a, _ = Allocation.objects.get_or_create(
            line=OrderLine.from_domain(domain_line),
            batch=django_batch,
        )
        return a
```

Then a port and adapter are defined for the repository pattern in
[`src/allocation/adapters/repository.py`](https://github.com/cosmicpython/code/blob/appendix_django/src/allocation/adapters/repository.py)

```py
# pylint: disable=no-member, no-self-use
from typing import Set
import abc
from allocation.domain import model
from djangoproject.alloc import models as django_models


class AbstractRepository(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen = set()  # type: Set[model.Batch]

    def add(self, batch: model.Batch):
        self.seen.add(batch)

    def get(self, reference) -> model.Batch:
        p = self._get(reference)
        if p:
            self.seen.add(p)
        return p

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _get(self, reference):
        raise NotImplementedError


class DjangoRepository(AbstractRepository):
    def add(self, batch):
        super().add(batch)
        self.update(batch)

    def update(self, batch):
        django_models.Batch.update_from_domain(batch)

    def _get(self, reference):
        return (
            django_models.Batch.objects.filter(reference=reference)
            .first()
            .to_domain()
        )

    def list(self):
        return [b.to_domain() for b in django_models.Batch.objects.all()]
```

Along with the domain models
[`src/allocation/domain/model.py`](https://github.com/cosmicpython/code/blob/appendix_django/src/allocation/domain/model.py)

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from typing import Optional, List, Set


class OutOfStock(Exception):
    pass


def allocate(line: OrderLine, batches: List[Batch]) -> str:
    try:
        batch = next(b for b in sorted(batches) if b.can_allocate(line))
        batch.allocate(line)
        return batch.reference
    except StopIteration:
        raise OutOfStock(f"Out of stock for sku {line.sku}")


@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class OrderLine:
    orderid: str
    sku: str
    qty: int


class Batch:
    def __init__(self, ref: str, sku: str, qty: int, eta: Optional[date]):
        self.reference = ref
        self.sku = sku
        self.eta = eta
        self._purchased_quantity = qty
        self._allocations = set()  # type: Set[OrderLine]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Batch {self.reference}>"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Batch):
            return False
        return other.reference == self.reference

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.reference)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.eta is None:
            return False
        if other.eta is None:
            return True
        return self.eta > other.eta

    def allocate(self, line: OrderLine):
        if self.can_allocate(line):
            self._allocations.add(line)

    def deallocate(self, line: OrderLine):
        if line in self._allocations:
            self._allocations.remove(line)

    @property
    def allocated_quantity(self) -> int:
        return sum(line.qty for line in self._allocations)

    @property
    def available_quantity(self) -> int:
        return self._purchased_quantity - self.allocated_quantity

    def can_allocate(self, line: OrderLine) -> bool:
        return self.sku == line.sku and self.available_quantity >= line.qty
```